# Excel: Applying SUMIF to a range of values?

Tags: excel, function, sumifs

I want to get the sum of values represented by `1,2,3,4`

eg: `=SUMIF(D5:D23,"1",G5:G23)+SUMIF(D5:D23,"2",G5:G23)+SUMIF(D5:D23,"3",G5:G23)+SUMIF(D5:D23,"4",G5:G23)`

How can I do this operation? Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIFS(G5:G23,D5:D23,">0",D5:D23,"<5")
```

You want to sum all values from `G5:G23` where the value from `D5:D23` is greater than 0 and less than 5. So you require 2 criteria. `>0` and `<5`.

Here is the function:

```
SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range1,criteria1,sum_range,[criteria_range2,criteria2],...)
```

Example:

[image]

---

**Edit**

Is think you want a vertical lookup - `VLOOKUP()`

**Formulas:**

- **G6**: `=VALUE(VLOOKUP(D6,$B$25:$E$30,2,FALSE))`
- **H6**: `=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("Valve",VLOOKUP(D6,$B$25:$E$30,3,FALSE))>0,$D$23,0),0)`
- **I6**: `=E6*$D$22`
- **J6**: `=SUM(G6:I6)`

Now select `G6:J6`, grab the handle at the bottom right, and drag to fill rows `G7:J7` to `G20:J20`.

Now sum up all the columns.

[image]

Here is the file completed: http://www.filedropper.com/wpmccardiocosts_1

You should check this out, it is very handy: http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/tutorial-how-to-decide-which-excel-lookup-formula-to-use/

Comment: This gives the total of the entire column.What I want is to get the total of values corresponding to each number 1,2,3,4.

Comment: What values are you summing?

Answer (score 1):

It may be simpler to use an array entered formula using SUM and IF:

```
=SUM(IF(D3:D23={1,2,3,4},G3:G23))
```

entered using [ctrl]+[shift]+[enter]  (an array formula)

This will allow for use of many variables in place of 1,2,3,4 such as not continuous numbers, text ect.